# Data deletion from database dynamically using delete request in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, http

I am using normal http request for deleting value from mysql database using node.js. But right now, only values are deleted statically not dynamically. I want to delete the data dynamically by providing the id.

```
const server = http.createServer();
const reqUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  if (reqUrl.pathname === '/delete'){

   req.on('end', () => {                        
       let sql = "Delete from students where id=12";     
        connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
         if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        });
        })
    res.end();   
   }
});
```

now, after running this code [localhost:3000/delete](http://www.example.com/)  only the id=12 is deleted all time. But I want to do this  [localhost:3000/delete?id=12](http://www.example.com/) giving input values as id.

I tried to give sql command as **"Delete from students where id=?"** , but it gave errors. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be simple.

You just need to receive the param from your request and append it to string.

Here's your updated code.

```
server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  if (reqUrl.pathname === '/delete'){

   req.on('end', () => {    
       let studid = req.query.id; //Get the student id                    
       let sql = "Delete from students where id="+studid; //append it to query     
        connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
         if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        });
        })
    res.end();   
   }
});
```

Comment: but how can I access the id, as it's auto incremented. By giving this, i got reference error, as id is not defined.

Comment: Are you passing id as query param. Can you please log `req.query` and let me know what you are getting? Also, you should be passing `id`  from request url.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Values are going to db through parse(body) using 'querystring'

Comment: Can you please confirm what is the url you are actually constructing to hit this method? Also please log **req.query** and see what you are getting..